# UILocalNotification scheduleLocalNotification slightly delayed?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, nsnotificationcenter, uiapplicationdelegate

After calling `scheduleLocalNotification:` on the`UIApplication` singleton, I notice on *some* occasions that the array of notifications returned by `scheduledLocalNotifications` on the`UIApplication` singleton does in fact not include the just scheduled notification.

This has not been a problem until now, or not that I am aware of. Have been using the assumption that local notifications are available right after they are scheduled.

Should we assume that scheduling of local notifications occur on some background thread by the OS, and not expect them to be visible right away after schedule?

Because I *am* updating my UI depending on if that notification is there or not...

Can anyone find an official word on this? I have not found any discussion.

Comment: check on device. Delay is mostly on simulator.

Comment: I always develop on device. Pretty consistent problem for now, but still not 100% (which is troublesome). I am suspecting that the current generation of devices are so fast that the current thread where I am scheduling those on jump on to the place where they check the scheduled array before the suspected bg thread can finish the scheduling. If I input some debug logs between scheduling and the array checking, the problem mostly goes away - the debug log probably delays stuff by enough milliseconds that the other thread has enough time to finish the scheduling. Or something.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: scheduleLocalNotification: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/scheduledLocalNotifications

> This method may be faster than using when scheduling a large number of
> notifications.

`scheduledLocalNotifications` can be directly assigned and the docs say that it can be faster than `scheduleLocalNotification:`. I understand that the later method can be slow.

You should just try to use `scheduledLocalNotifications` directly.

Comment: So they implicitly mean that `scheduleLocalNotification:` can be *slow*..? Anyway, I am only scheduling one... but still see this lag, or whatever it is. I will try to assign to the array directly. I guess it should be safe to create a mutable array frmo any existing contents, then add to that array.

Comment: I tried it, and while it might be faster for many notifications (can't say anything about that, I'm just using one), it does not change. If I check the array count (which I just set!), it's 0 (!). It must mean the OS does some "slow" processing in the background for a bit too long...

Comment: I know that there is some optimization made under the hood to preserve battery life when `firing` notification: the system can slightly delay some notification to group them with other ones or other event in order to wake the processor once and not many times. But I'm not aware of such optimization when `scheduling` notifications.